# Using C#/Java/Visual Basic to populate a Word 2007 template

Tags: c#, java, ms-word, populate, rhapsody

I've recently been given a task to populate a Word 2007 file with information retrieved from Rhapsody using the Rhapsody API. I'm not super familiar with Rhapsody, but I'll learn. I'm having difficulty tracking down a good way to write a program that can write to a formatted (read: tables) word document. I'm best at java, but I'm capable of using C#, C++, or VB. The problem seems to be that all options for java require the use of 3rd party libraries, and I'm not sure if I'm comfortable using them. All of the languages available in the Microsoft Visual Studio seem to have options for writing out to a Word Document, but I can't seem to figure them out. What would be my simplest option in attempting to tackle this task?

Comment: whats wrong with the Java 3rd party libraries? Post some code from them to show us what wasnt working or what you dont understand

Answer (score 2):

Aspose words does a really good job integrating C# with MS word.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Comment: It seems it costs money. I have no budget for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you already tried all features of Rhapsody Reporter Plus (in built) and Rational Publishing Engine (additional licenses might be required). With them you can produce html, pdf, word documents...

If this is not your use case and you need your own plug ins in java, we have good experiences with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), which I could recommend.

I don't understand why you might have issues using 3rd party libraries, when you write everything by yourself you might end doing such a similar library, expending of course "some" time and "some" headaches until having it ready...